# Does any one implemented latest Google Analytics with iOS

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I used step by step instruction here :
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/#initialize

But still my hit is not being recorded. I can see in the debugging window its say something about dispatching number and start tracking again.

My another concern it what they assigned to tracker and then never used it. 
Am I missing something. Someone please shed some light.

I have looked over the internet, there are all old and referring to old google analytics library which is having only two files. GANTracker.h and libGoogleAnalytics.a

New library got bunch of files hence the way they have implemented. 
Code is pretty straight forward I dont know what it is not tracking the hits.

And Yes I have created tracking ID and I am familiar with the Google Analytics as I used it in past to track my websites and blogs.
I would appreciate if someone can give me some right pointers. Thanks.

As log window was having quite a lot info I have created a "paste"
http://pastie.org/7468881

Comment: Could you add to the question what is the log window showing?